# Is it possible to disable Ghostery Smart Blocking

Tags: firefox, internet, ghostery, privacy-extensions

I discovered today that Ghostery is allowing trackers (e.g. google) to function even though I have block all trackers set.  It appears that their Smart Blocking overrides your choice to block all and allows trackers they deem safe.

> [What is Smart Blocking?](https://www.ghostery.com/faqs/what-is-smart-blocking/)
>
> We developed our automatic Smart Blocking feature to make it easier
>   for users to optimize their browsing experience and blocking choices. 
>   It automatically blocks slow or non-secure trackers, for example, and
>   allows certain trackers that we know may cause breakage on popular
>   websites when blocked. This function is run locally and does not use
>   any personal data

Is it possible to disable the "Smart Blocking" feature and truly block ALL trackers?  I've gone through the Settings multiple times and I don't see that option.

Comment: I strongly suggest you use uBlock Origin instead. There’s plenty of filter lists available. If you don’t want tracking, you’ll have to block almost all ads anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ghostery is antiquated. Use better tracking protection such as [uBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/).

Your tag says Firefox. With [Total Cookie Protection](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2021/02/23/total-cookie-protection/), there are really no benefits of using it. uBlock Origin provides every protection Ghostery has, plus more.

People in the privacy community avoid it because they feel its business practices have been more shady in the past, such as their use of the option GhostRank, which sent information about ads that were blocked to advertising companies.[3](https://lifehacker.com/ad-blocking-extension-ghostery-actually-sells-data-to-a-514417864/)

There is also the fact that while both are (now) open-source, Ghostery is owned by a company, while uBlock is maintained largely by users. We all know the function of a company.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1200502)

Comment: Thanks, will do.

Comment: @Eternal482223, We are not harassing you, all posts are reviewed by other users to make sure they comply. You CAN suggest a different product as a solution, but then do a review of it.  Not just a name, and not just a link.